# How to rewrite newer ARM instructions missing on ARMv4t like CLZNE, PLD etc.?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to build a large piece of software on an ARMv4t platform with the gcc tools. The software I'm trying to build contains some assembly code that seems to target at least ARMv5. This results in the assembly code containing instructions like `BLX`, `CLZNE`, `PLD`, `VMRS`, `VMSR`, `SMULBB`, `SMLABB`, `LDREX`, `STREX`, `STREXEQ` and possibly others that are not supported on ARMv4t.

This obviously results in error messages like this during build:

```
Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `[some instruction]'
```

So I tried to find alternatives for these instructions in order to rewrite them in such a way that they would work on ARMv4t as well. And while I found a way to rewrite `BLX arg` as `MOV lr, pc;  BL arg` (this works because I'm not using Thumb mode, i.e. I'm using `-marm` as a compiler flag) I'm pretty lost with the other missing instructions.

Does anyone see a chance to rewrite the given instructions (preferrably with macros) so that the software will build on ARMv4t as well? If yes: how?

Comment: A good start would be to get an understanding of what those instructions do (consult the ARM Architecture Reference Manual). For example, does your ARMv4 part have NEON or VFP extensions? If not, `VMRS` is probably irrelevant. Does it have cache memory? If not, `PLD` is probably irrelevant. Etc.

Comment: You should just write `BLX arg` as `BL arg`. They both set LR to the address of the following instruction, so the `MOV lr, pc` doesn't do anything useful. The only difference between the BL and BLX instrucitons is that the later can change modes.

Comment: Michael during the armv4 era they didnt even have VFP it was the FPA and rare anyway.  if you wanted to take that route then instead just switch to arm mode and come back much easier.  Ross Ridge, the other difference between BL and BLX is that they can change modes on the way in not just on the way out, you cant bl from arm to thumb or thumb to arm you have to bx or blx (or in some architectures pop/ldmia)  so neither the move pc nor the replace blx with bl actually replaces a blx, you have to do an if lsbit of address (assuming you know the mode of the code you are in) and then bl or bx

Comment: armv4 and armv5 were quite similar, but still there are the subtle differences that happened over time as to how pop/ldmia can or cant be used to change between arm and thumb, you really need the ARM ARM, I think they now lump the original ARM ARM (architectural reference manual) into an armv6 manual, but that covers v4 v5 and v6 then with v7 they started a new one

Comment: The ARMv6+ load/store exclusives (`ldrex`/`strex`) are possibly the most worrying - depending on what exactly they are used for you could have a significant headache rewriting that functionality with nothing but `swp` and/or disabling interrupts at your disposal.

Comment: Depending on how those instructions are being used, a simple macro replacement is not possible because you will need extra registers to implement the functions being replaced. CLZ could be done with a lookup table, but SMULXX and SMLAXX are signed 16x16 bit multiplies that can access the top and bottom half of registers. A better strategy is to understand what the code needs to do and rewrite it in ARMv4 instructions.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. Since the "large piece of software" is actually the Android platform that I wanted to build for my (pretty old) automotive navigation system device - I guess I can give up that project. ;)